# How to re-upload same version to iTunes connect

Tags: xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I was porting my old application to iOS 11, and once finished, I archived the build to upload it to the app store using xcode organizer.

Now there have been several issues with app icons, asset catalog and the like, which made me re-build and re-upload. Originally I wanted to upload version 3.0.5, and this is the version I created in the iTunes connect portal.

However after fixing the errors I received via mail after, I would not be able to upload a fixed version with the same version number. It would tell me that a binary upload with the same version already exists. 
Now I have not found any way to *remove* said already existing binary, since iTunes connect is *not* showing it anywhere (it was rejected because of the errors anyway).
So how can this be done? I actually ended up distributing version *3.0.8* because of this, but I feel there must be a better way?

Same question BTW for TestFlight, where the very same happened to me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only way to upload a new build to iTC is to increase the Build number.

Note that you don't have to increase the Version number.  Build number and Version number are two different settings in the General configuration tab for an app Target in Xcode, and they do not have to be the same.

Comment: Okay thanks, for some reason I always kept version + build in sync. So obviously I shall use the build number how it is supposed to be used from now on :)